# Question involving direct summand

Tags: modules, direct-sum

Lets $L,N$ submodules of $M$ such that $L \cap N$ is direct summand of $L$ and $N$. Show that $L \cap N$ is direct summand of $L+N$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Well, if $L \cap N$ is direct summand of $L$ and $N$ then there exists $L'$ and $N'$ such that $L \simeq L \cap N \oplus L'$ and $N \simeq L \cap N \oplus N'$. I was thinking about $L+N \simeq L \cap N \oplus (L' \oplus N')$, but I don't know if it is correct and how to prove it.

Another way is using splitting sequences. Can you help me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with splitting sequences is, at least to me, much easier.

We know that $L \cap N \hookrightarrow L$ and $L \cap N \hookrightarrow N$ are direct summands, and so we have splittings

- $\pi_L : L \to L \cap N$
- $\pi_R : N \to L \cap N$

with the bonus property that including and splitting is the identity (this is more or less the definition of a splitting):

- $L \cap N \hookrightarrow L \overset{\pi_L}{\longrightarrow} L \cap N$ is the identity
- $L \cap N \hookrightarrow N \overset{\pi_N}{\longrightarrow} L \cap N$ is the identity

But to *show* that $L \cap N$ is a summand of $L+N$, we want to show that there is such a splitting $\pi_{L+N} : L+N \to L \cap N$... Do you see a good way to build such a splitting? I'll give another hint under the fold.

> By the universal property of direct sums, we have a map $\pi_L + \pi_N : L+N \to L \cap N$ which sends $l + n \mapsto \pi_L(l) + \pi_N(n)$. Notice it's important that $\pi_L$ and $\pi_N$ agree on the intersection, but of course they do since they are both the identity on the intersection.
>
>  Can you show that this is the desired splitting? That is, can you show that
>  $L \cap N \hookrightarrow L + N \overset{\pi_L + \pi_N}{\longrightarrow} L \cap N$ is the identity?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Wait, In my definition of direct summand I just have that $L = L \cap N \oplus L'$ for some $L'$. I know that if we have a short exact sequence $0 \to L \cap N \to L \to N' \to 0$ and it splits then we have split $\pi_L$ you've mentioned in the beginning, so $L \cap N$ is direct summand of $L$. Is the reciprocal correct? I guess you're using the reciprocal in the beggining, but what are your short exact sequence?

Comment: A submodule $M$ of $N$ is a direct summand if and only if the inclusion $M \hookrightarrow N$ splits. You can find a proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma), for instance.

Comment: Thank you,now I got it.